Kibana security must be enabled to use Fleet
[plugins.fleet.fleet_authz_router] Kibana security must be enabled to use Fleet when i go to kibana i can not add a fleet server enter image description here
equesting service_token from Kibana.
2024-04-18T12:36:57.319066898Z Error: request to get security token from Kibana failed: Kibana security must be enabled to use Fleet: %!w(<nil>)
version: '3'

services:
    elasticsearch:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.13.2
        container_name: elasticsearch
        environment:
            - discovery.type=single-node
            - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=test
            - xpack.security.enabled=false
        ports:
            - "9200:9200"

    kibana:
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.13.2
        container_name: kibana
        ports:
            - "5601:5601"
        depends_on:
            - elasticsearch
        environment:
            - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=https://elasticsearch:9200
            - SERVERNAME=kibana
            - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=kibana_system
            - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=test
            - XPACK_REPORTING_KIBANASERVER_HOSTNAME=localhost
            - SERVER_SSL_ENABLED=false
            - xpack.security.enabled=true
            - xpack.security.authc.providers=[]


    apm-server:
        image: docker.elastic.co/apm/apm-server:8.13.2
        container_name: apm-server
        ports:
            - "8200:8200"
        depends_on:
            - elasticsearch
            - kibana
        environment:
            - OUTPUT_ELASTICSEARCH_ENABLED=true
            - OUTPUT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=["elasticsearch:9200"]
            - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS="http://elasticsearch:9200"

    fleet-server:
        image: docker.elastic.co/beats/elastic-agent:8.6.0
        container_name: fleet-server
        restart: "always"
        ports:
            - "9243:9243"
        depends_on:
            - elasticsearch
            - kibana
        environment:
            FLEET_SERVER_ENABLE: true
            FLEET_SERVER_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST: "elasticsearch:9201"
            FLEET_SERVER_PORT: 9243
            FLEET_SERVER_INSECURE_HTTP: false
            KIBANA_HOST: "http://kibana:5601"
            KIBANA_FLEET_SETUP: false


This message is actually misleading. Elasticsearch security should be set to true.
xpack.security.enabled=true

Then restart Elasticsearch.
In this case you should secure your inter-node connection, which means you should wait ca. 30 seconds till Elasticsearch is up again, then change the credentials:
/usr/share/bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token --scope kibana
/usr/share/kibana/bin/kibana-verification-code
/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/ elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic -i

When you restart your Kibana, you can use these credentials to login.
